# "Засыпает" приложение node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, rest, express

Пишу приложение на Node.js. В целом, все работает так, как надо. Но иногда Node.js как бы засыпает и не отвечает на запросы. Запускаю его через powerShell "node имя_файла.js" (в cmd то же самое). Если открыть powerShell и нажать ctrl+z во время того, как Node.js "cпит", то оно отвечает на запрос и дальше работает, как надо. Проблемы возникают только с post-запросами. Вот сам код:

```
let express = require("express");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

/*Constants*/
let masters = require("./constants/masters").masters;
let users = require("./constants/users").users;
let times = require("./constants/times").times;
let places = require("./constants/places").places;
let locations = require("./constants/locations").locations;


/*Array to store records*/
let userRecords = [];

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/account', function (req, res) {
    console.log("/account requested");
    let infoForRecord = {
        masters, times, places
    };
    res.send(infoForRecord);
});

app.get('/locations', function (req, res) {
    console.log("/main_page requested");
    res.send(locations);
});


app.post('/records', function (req, res) {
    if ((!req.body) || (!req.query)) {
        return res.sendStatus(400)
    }
    console.log("/records requested");
    let {username, id, time, place, master} = req.query;
    userRecords.push({username, id, time, place, master});
    console.log(userRecords);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({status: "ok"}));
});

app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    if ((!req.body) || (!req.query)) {
        return res.sendStatus(400)
    }
    console.log("/authenticate requested");
    let found = false;
    for (let user of users) {
        if ((user.username === req.query.username) &&
            (user.password === req.query.password)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    found ? res.send(JSON.stringify({status: "ok"})) : res.send(JSON.stringify({status: "not_found"}));
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Эта проблема с Node.js или с ОС, которая может усыпить процесс?

Comment: какая версия Ноды у Вас?

Comment: Моя версия Node.js 10.11.0

Comment: Я несколько дней назад поставил 10.12.0 и тоже стал замечать подобные провисы. Правда, все это происходит в процессе разработки. В реальном проекте стоит 10.4.0, с кучей POST-запросов, там такого не замечал.